# React Redux: how do you access response of post in component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working on a project based on this: https://github.com/bradtraversy/lead_manager_react_django

I need to access the pk of a newly created object. I can console.log the values I need in the action but cannot figure out how to use it in the component. Redux tools shows the new values as well in the diff.

What am I missing?

Action:

```
export const addPlan = (plan) => (dispatch, getState) => {
axios.post("/api/plans/", plan, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
        dispatch(createMessage({ createPlan: 'Plan created.'}));
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_PLAN,
            payload: res.data
        });
    }).catch(err => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)));
```

Reducer:

```
        case ADD_PLAN:
        return {
            ...state,
            plans: [...state.plans, action.payload]
        };
```

mapStateToProps in component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
     plans: state.plans.plans,
     production: state.plans.production
});
```

Comment: How does your current component that need to consume the api data look like? You can use [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start#connect) HOC or use redux hooks in the copmonent that needs to access the data  and extract is with [mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, everything was setup correctly but I just didn't know where to get access to the new props. I used componentWillReceiveUpdate and a little logic to prevent default and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mapStateToProps` with `connect` inside the component.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { plans } = state
    return { todoList }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent)
```

You can read more about connecting your component with redux store [here](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate)